# I want NAV price as per (Today date minus 1) date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One is NAV where product daily new price is updated. Second is TDK table where item wise stock is available.

Now I want to get a summery report as per buyer name where all product wise total will come and from table one latest price will come.

I have tried below query...

```
SELECT dbo.TDK.buyer, dbo.NAV.Product_Name, sum(dbo.TDK.TD_UNITS) as Units, sum(dbo.TDK.TD_AMT) as 'Amount',dbo.NAV.NAValue
FROM dbo.TDK INNER JOIN
     dbo.NAV
     ON dbo.TDK.Products = dbo.NAV.Product_Name
group by dbo.TDK.buyer, dbo.NAV.Product_Name, dbo.NAV.NAValue
```

Imnportant: Common columns in both tables...
Table one NAV has column as Products
Table two TDK has column as Product_Name

If I have NAValue 4 records for one product then this query shows 4 lines with same total.

What I need??

1. I want this query to show only one line with latest NAValue price.
2. I want display one more line with Units*NAValue (latest) as "Latest Market Value".

Please guide.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What field contains the quote date? I am assuming you have a DATIME field, quoteDate, in dbo.NAV table and my other assumption is that you only store the Date part (i.e. mid-night, time = 00:00:00).

```
SELECT
    t.buyer,
    n.Product_Name,
    sum(t.TD_UNITS) as Units,
    sum(t.TD_AMT) as 'Amount',
    n.NAValue
FROM dbo.TDK t
INNER JOIN dbo.NAV n
    ON t.Products = n.Product_Name
    AND n.quoteDate > getdate()-2
group by t.buyer, n.Product_Name, n.NAValue, n.QuoteDate
```

GetDate() will give you the current date and time. Subtracting 2 would get it before yesterday but after the day before yesterday.

Also, add n.quoteDate in your select and group by. Even though you don't need it, in case that one day you have a day of bad data with double record in NAV table, one with midnight time and another with 6 PM  time.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It has solved my 100% problem.

Can I multiplication of units column and NAValue column by displaying results in a new column?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, sum(t.TD_AMT)*n.NAValue as [LatestMarketValue]

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  I think you just want `APPLY`:

```
SELECT t.buyer, n.Product_Name, t.TD_UNITS as Units, t.TD_AMT as Amount, n.NAValue
FROM dbo.TDK t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) n.*
      FROM dbo.NAV n
      WHERE t.Products = n.Product_Name
      ORDER BY ?? DESC  -- however you define "latest"
     ) n;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply...
It is showing an error...

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @Vinay . . . Dod you replace `??` with the appropriate column name that specifies the "latest" row?